# How to minimize ,the rails by default textfield

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= f.text_field(:start_date,:size=>5)%>
```

Is it possible to reduce the length of the text field in a form?
I used :`size => 5`, it doesn't reduce the size of text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `:class => "input-small"` in your text_field_tag.

This uses the relative sizing classes of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with the solution: [Text area - Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area)